# Find if a car with booster and varying throttle acceleration can reach target

Tags: beginner, c

This is a personal hobby project, I'm in control of all decisions made regarding my bot, but I can't change anything about the physics of the game (offline-only, and it's approved by the game devs - so don't worry!) I have a car, and the car is facing its target. All it needs to do is drive forwards, however, this is much more complicated than just a constant forwards acceleration.

The problem:

The car can only gain acceleration via the throttle when it's on the ground (kind of, more on that in a bit) but it also has A FREAKIN' ROCKET on the back, which propels it forwards at a constant rate in the air and on the ground. The rocket needs fuel, which goes from 0-100 (easiest to think of this as a percent - however, if the car has more than 100% rocket fuel, then due to the systems in place this signifies that the car has unlimited rocket fuel). The throttle acceleration is dependant on the speed of the car. The faster it's going, the less acceleration pressing the throttle provides, until the acceleration reaches 0.

At a certain point, the car jumps and can no longer accelerate using the throttle, but due to some magic, the car actually gets a bit acceleration (idk it's one of those bugs turned feature and it needs to be accounted for). The rocket (if there's rocket fuel) can also speed up the car in the air, and by a lot. I don't care about the z axis, as that's handled elsewhere.

With this knowledge at hand, I want to figure out ahead of time if the car can travel a certain distance in a certain time with a certain jump time. Initially, the car may or may not be at rest, it may be traveling forwards (positive velocity) or backwards (negative velocity), and the car may or may not have rocket fuel. The jump time may also be 0, which signifies that there is no jump for the car to make.

Program includes:

```c
#include <math.h>
```

In my program, rocket fuel is referred to as 'boost'. Here are my constants - I've added comments to clear some things up:

```c
static const double simulation_dt = 1. / 20.; // Delta time to run the simulation runs at
static const double physics_dt = 1. / 120.; // Delta time that the actual game runs at

static const double boost_consumption = 100. * (1. / 3.);
static const double max_boost = 100;

// all distance measurements are depicted in centimeters
static const double aerial_throttle_accel = 100. * (2. / 3.); // due to some magic, the car actually gets a bit acceleration - don't question it
static const double brake_force = 3500; // when trying to acceleration in the opposite direction that you're traveling, ur speed decreases by this amount every second
static const double min_simulation_distance = 25; // If we get closer to the target than this, we consider the simulation done
static const double max_speed = 2300;
static const double max_speed_no_boost = 1410;

// the relationship between velocity and throttle acceleration is mostly linear
static const double start_throttle_accel_m = -36. / 35.;
static const double start_throttle_accel_b = 1600;
static const double end_throttle_accel_m = -16;
static const double end_throttle_accel_b = 160;
```

Converting velocity to the acceleration given by the throttle:

```c
double throttle_acceleration(double *car_velocity_x)
{
    double x = fabs(*car_velocity_x);

    if (x >= max_speed_no_boost)
        return 0;

    // use y = mx + b to find the throttle acceleration
    if (x < 1400)
        return start_throttle_accel_m * x + start_throttle_accel_b;

    x -= 1400;
    // there's a very sharp dropoff here that brings the acceleration to 0 by the time the velocity is 1410
    return end_throttle_accel_m * x + end_throttle_accel_b;
}
```

Here's my code for solving this problem, which is horribly inefficient but it does get the job done... it works by doing a sort of simulation, processing changes tick-by-tick with no optimization.

```c
_Bool can_reach_target_forwards(double *max_time, double *jump_time, double *boost_accel, double *distance_remaining, double *car_speed, unsigned char *car_boost, double *max_speed_reduction)
{
    double v = *car_speed;
    double t = 0;
    double b = *car_boost;
    double d = *distance_remaining;
    double ba_dt = *boost_accel * simulation_dt;
    double ms = max_speed - ceil(*max_speed_reduction);
    double ms_ba_dt = ms - ba_dt;
    double bc_dt = boost_consumption * simulation_dt;
    double bk_dt = brake_force * simulation_dt;

    while (d > min_simulation_distance && t <= *max_time && (v <= 0 || d / v > *jump_time))
    {
        // if we're going backwards, then apply the braking acceleration... otherwise, apply the throttle acceleration
        v += (v < 0) ? bk_dt : throttle_acceleration(&v) * simulation_dt;

        // if we have boost & we're at less than max speed
        if (b > bc_dt && v < ms_ba_dt)
        {
            // apply velocity from boost and reduce boost amount accordingly
            v += ba_dt;
            if (b <= max_boost)
                b -= bc_dt;
        }

        // subtract the proper amount of distance and add the simulation delta time to the total time
        d -= v * simulation_dt;
        t += simulation_dt;
    }

    double th_dt = aerial_throttle_accel * simulation_dt;
    double ms_th_dt = ms - th_dt;

    // this is basically the same as above, but it's for after the car jumps (if it does at all)
    while (d > min_simulation_distance && t <= *max_time)
    {
        // yes, this IS max_speed, NOT max_speed_no_boost!
        if (v <= ms_th_dt)
            v += th_dt;

        if (b > bc_dt && v < ms_ba_dt)
        {
            v += ba_dt;
            if (b <= max_boost)
                b -= bc_dt;
        }

        d -= v * simulation_dt;
        t += simulation_dt;
    }

    return d <= min_simulation_distance;
}
```

I'm not very familiar with Calculus (I haven't gotten to that in school and it seems hard -_-), but I'm still wondering if there's anything that I can do that will speed up the function. Currently, it's speed is *acceptable*, but I would rather develop my programming/math skills and have it be *exceptional*. My bot runs at 120tps, so this function, along with a LOT of other things, needs to run in 8 milliseconds or (preferably much) less. Above all else the true purpose of this post is I want to learn where I need to improve. I'm relatively new to C (only a few months of experience, and I'm self-taught) and I would also love feedback on any C standards or C programming conventions that I'm violating. If there's any tips or tricks that would make using C easier, I'm all ears! Also, no, I'm not switching away from plain C (yet, at least.)

Comment: Does gravity remain constant, and is the constant 9.8m/sec^2? The problem you are describing was solved during WW2 by the navy for ballistics calculations. You shouldn't need a simulation.

Comment: I don't need to account for height. Just forwards speed. But yes, gravity does remain constant - but the car isn't airborne until the end. Also, I should mention that in the game there's no air resistance. With modifications, something like that could work. Idk how to do them tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Eliminate unused variables

Unused variables are a sign of poor quality code, and you don't want to write poor quality code. In this code, `physics_dt` is unused.  Your compiler is smart enough to tell you about this if you ask it nicely.

### Pass by value rather than by pointer

This code has a peculiar quirk that it uses pointers for every passed value.  Unless you're planning on altering the value, [plain old data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType) like this really should just passed by value rather than by pointer, so instead of this:

```
double throttle_acceleration(double *car_velocity_x)
{
    double x = fabs(*car_velocity_x);
```

Write this:

```
double throttle_acceleration(double car_velocity_x)
{
    double x = fabs(car_velocity_x);
```

The same is true for all of the other arguments.

### Provide complete code to reviewers

This is not so much a change to the code as a change in how you present it to other people.  Without the full context of the code and an example of how to use it, it takes more effort for other people to understand your code.  This affects not only code reviews, but also maintenance of the code in the future, by you or by others.  One good way to address that is by the use of comments.  Another good technique is to include test code showing how your code is intended to be used.

### Consider using structures

There are a great many variables and constants in this program.  The constants are generally named well, which is good.  However, I think I'd approach it a bit differently.  For the `throttle_acceleration`, I'd make that simply `acceleration` and write it like this:

```
double acceleration(double car_velocity_x)
{
    // the relationship between velocity and throttle acceleration 
    // is expressed as three piecewise linear equations
    static const struct {
        double min_x;   // minimum x value for this equation
        double m;       // slope of line
        double b;       // intercept of line
    } equation[3] = {
        { 1410,  0          ,     0 },
        { 1400, -16         , 22560 },
        { 0,    -36.0 / 35.0,  1600 },
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        if (car_velocity_x > equation[i].min_x) {
            return car_velocity_x * equation[i].m + equation[i].b;
        }
    }
    // if the velocity is negative, apply the brakes
    return brake_force;
}
```

This also has the effect of simplifying the code that uses it:

```
v += acceleration(v) * simulation_dt;
```

### Use `const` where practical

Many of the calculated values in `can_reach_target_forwards` are constants.  It may help the compiler create better code if you declare them as `const`.  Even if it doesn't it makes the code more understandable to human readers.

### Use a real `bool`

If you `#include <stdbool.h>` you can use a real `bool` as well as the constants `true` and `false` which can make your code a bit clearer.

### Don't repeat yourself

As the comments in the code note, the loops before and after the jump are nearly identical.  I think it would make sense to combine them.  Here's one way to do that:

```
bool on_ground = true;
for (double t = 0; 
        d > min_simulation_distance && t <= max_time; 
        t += simulation_dt) 
{
    if (on_ground &= (v <= 0 || d/v > jump_time)) {
        v += acceleration(v) * simulation_dt;
    } else {
        // no longer on the ground
        if (v <= ms_th_dt)
            v += th_dt;
    }
    // if we have boost & we're at less than max speed
    if (b > bc_dt && v < ms_ba_dt) {
        // apply boost
        v += ba_dt;
        if (b <= max_boost)
            b -= bc_dt;
    }
    // subtract the proper amount of distance 
    d -= v * simulation_dt;
}
```

Note that I have also converted `while` into `for` to make it clear which variable is being incremented.

### Consider a mathematical solution

As you suspected, there is a more mathematical way to approach this problem.  First, let's slightly reframe the problem as the question "how much time would it take to get to the target?"  We can designate that time as \$t_{f}\$ where the \$f\$ signifies final.  First, let's consider only deceleration from braking and acceleration from the throttle and ignore boost and jump time for the moment.

\$a(v) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
  3500 & v < 0 \\
  -\frac{36}{35}v  + 1600 & 0\leq v < 1400 \\
  -16v +22560 & 1400 \leq v < 1410 \\
  0 & 1410 \leq v \\
\end{array} 
\right. \$

Note that this is not exactly how the code is currently implemented, because at zero velocity, the current implementation actually gets acceleration due to braking which makes no physical sense.  I've taken the liberty of altering this, but there is likely little noticable difference.

Because only one of these is used at a time, we can break it into steps.  First, consider a start with a negative velocity so that we're moving away from the target.  In this phase we're just braking, so at any time \$t\$ during this phase, the velocity is:

$$ v(t) = v_0 + 3500t $$

It's easy to figure out how long it will take to get to zero velocity using algebra.

$$ 0 = v_0 + 3500t $$
$$ 3500t = -v_0 $$
$$ t =  \frac{-v_0}{3500} $$

Since we've been moving away from the target, how far away is the target now?  This is where calculus comes in handy, but I'll try to explain in a way that doesn't assume you already know calculus to whet your appetite for learning it (it's really not as hard as you might think).

We know that for each step in time, we have \$\Delta d = v(t)\Delta t\$ and so if we also account for the initial distance \$d_0\$ we have:

$$ d(t) = d_0 + \sum v(t) \Delta t $$

Expressing this in calculus notation is very similar:

$$ d(t) = d_0 + \int v(t) \delta t $$

Substituting the equation above, that expands to this:

$$ d(t) = d_0 + \int v_0 + 3500 \delta t $$

Now evaluating this integral is probably not something you've learned yet, but it's [actually quite simple](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/intpol.html) to evaluate integrals of simple polynomials.  The answer in this case is:

$$ d(t) = 1750 t^2 + v_0 t + d_0 $$

So given that the time to zero velocity is \$v_0/-3500\$ we can evaluate:

$$ d\left(\frac{v_0}{-3500}\right) = 1750 \left(\frac{v_0}{-3500}\right)^2 + v_0\left(\frac{v_0}{-3500}\right) + d_0 $$

$$ = \frac{v_0^2}{7000} + d_0 $$

So now we are at zero velocity at a time and distance we can easily calculate.  The next phase is where \$0\leq v < 1400\$ and we can perform a similar analysis, but because in this phase, our equation has the velocity depending on itself, the solution uses an [ordinary differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) which is often taught after introductory calculus.

Without showing the derivation, the solution is:

$$ v(t) = \frac{35 v_0 + 56000 t}{36t + 35} $$

Since we want to know when \$v(t) = 1400\$, a little algebra yields:

$$ t = \frac{1400-v_0}{160} $$

We can do a similar exercise for each kind of acceleration and also then add in boost and jump time and eventually come up with one big equation that incorporates all of these and yields the time required to get to the destination given all of the variables.

In short, while it's a bit tedious and involves some mathematics you might not yet have learned, there is definitely a way to solve this analytically without resorting to simulation.  I hope this inspires you to keep learning more mathematics as well as helping you improve your software.

Comment: Wow! This looks like a lot of great stuff! Thanks for all of the info - I'll have to review the mathematical solution to my problem later when I can tackle it with the focus and time that will be required. I agree with you on most of what you said, except with a few things like the unused variable which is used in a part of my program that isn't related (my fault, not yours).

Answer (score 0):

What's this?

```
_Bool
```

Probably you should be using `<stdbool.h>`.

Why is this -

```
double *car_velocity_x
```

a pointer? You should be able to pass by value here. The same applies to `can_reach_target_forwards`.

1400 should be added to your named constants.

```
// this is basically the same as above
```

should tell you that you should be factoring out common code into another function.

Comment: `stdbool.h` only existed after C99, and before that you just used `_Bool`, and 0 for `false` and 1 for `true`. It's down to personal preference, for me.

Comment: I use pointers because copying the values isn't needed, and I've heard that you should use pointers where possible because it's faster. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @VirxEC Yes, the rule "always use pointers" is incorrect. Pointers are just normal values as well, so you need to analyze which one is faster, the pointer value or the actual value. Typical sizes of pointers are 16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit, depending on the platform. The size of a `double` is typically 64 bit. But if you pass the argument by pointer, that pointer must be _dereferenced_, which costs another memory access and 1 or 2 CPU instructions. The rule "pass pointers instead of values" typically starts to make sense for data structures that have the size of 3 or more pointers.